# CodedUI - Can build-deploy-test workflow close IE browser instance on test agent machine?

Tags: coded-ui-tests, microsoft-test-manager, mtm, lab-management

I am using build deploy test workflow to execute testcases on Lab environment-CodedUI. Browser IE instance remains open after test execution is over.

I am thinking if I can add something to my build workflow, which send instructions on test agent machine to close that browser instance. Is that possible?

I execute testcases in bunch. No testcase close the browser instance. They work on same browser instance to save login time. Hence I want to close browser once execution is over

Regards,
Gbhavsar

Comment: I think you need to handle that in your CodedUI test method. There is no in-build mechanism to do that.

Comment: I suppose you are using VS/MTM 2010, so just for your information: starting with VS/MTM 2012 browser is closed automatically after each test. So if you want this behaviour and can update to 2012, that would be the easiest way for you.

Comment: you can add a .bat file that will close the IE process oce the tests have finished running

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inbuilt functionality of settings

```
browserInstance.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = true
```

or use a custom .bat file to close/kill all open IE/Chrome/FireFox processes in your post test script.

See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/11/08/coded-ui-test-why-does-application-close-after-each-test-in-visual-studio-2012/